# removing a variable from $PATH on terminal

Tags: macos, path, terminal

Every time I open terminal, I get this message:

-bash: “BT2_HOME=/home/stevensi/bowtie2-2.0.0-beta7/”: No such file or directory 
-bash: “export: command not found
-bash: “export: command not found

I would like to remove BT2_HOME from my path variable. What is the best way to do this?

So far, I tried:

unset BT2_HOME

but this doesn't resolve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, unset is used to delete variables, and $PATH is not. Looking here and there i found that:

[I want to remove an entry in my $PATH](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81939/i-want-to-remove-an-entry-in-my-path)

Try following that post and let me know if it works.

I should be writing this as a comment, but i'm kinda new and don't have enough reputation, sorry :(